# How to give names/labels to topics in LDA

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, topic-model, lda

I want to give labels to different topics created using LDA. I don't want to do it manually. I saw some papers on automatic labeling but I am still confused.

How can I use the information produced by LDA to automatically generate names to the topics generated?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is late to answer, but it may turn out to be helpful for others.

LDA presents all topics as a mixture of keywords with their weights
For example, in gensim implementation it looks like this:

topic #0: 0.009*river + 0.008*lake + 0.006*island + 0.005*mountain + 0.004*area + 0.004*park + 0.004*antarctic + 0.004*south + 0.004*mountains + 0.004*dam

So you may name a topic using the keywords with the largest weights (like River+Lake).
Or you may use something like WordNet to find the most common hypernym for them.
For example, in python you can do it like this.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wn.synset('river.n.01').lowest_common_hypernyms(wn.synset('lake.n.01'))
```

Comment: i am not working with English so the option of wordnet is not suitable in my case.

Comment: There are wordnets for other languages, search for Multilingual wordnet with your favorite search engine.